# Different OGC WKT strings for EPSG:3135 in reference sources

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg, well-known-text

I found two sources for getting WKT strings:

1. https://www.spatialreference.org/
2. https://epsg.io/

But there are differences in OGC WKT string in these two sites for coordinate system EPSG:3135. The string contains extra axis (AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AXIS["Easting",EAST]) on [www.spatialreference.org](http://www.spatialreference.org).

What definition is the correct one? What source should I use?

Comment: EPSG registry is epsg.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your references are not trustworthy. The sites contain a modified copy of some version of the EPSG database that is available from https://epsg.org. Some CRS records in those services tend to be broken and users should always check the official site if correct information is important.

From https://epsg.org/crs_3135/ETRS89-ETRS-GK28FIN.html? you can see that the correct axis order of that CRS is Northing-Easting.

The source code of the epsg.io site is in the GitHub https://github.com/maptiler/epsg.io. There it should be possible to check what EPSG database version is in use. However, right now the https://epsg.io informs "Powered by EPSG database 10.076" but in the GitHub I can see that the last update was "Update EPSG Dataset ver 9.8". It looks like MapTiler is using some other repository as main.

The Proj and WKT strings can also be checked with the projinfo utility https://proj.org/apps/projinfo.html. It supports the following CRS endodings:

> -o formats formats is a comma separated combination of: all, default, PROJ, WKT_ALL, WKT2:2015, WKT2:2019, WKT1:GDAL, WKT1:ESRI, PROJJSON,
> SQL.

Example: Get EPSG:3135 definition as ESRI WKT

```
projinfo epsg:3135 -o WKT1:ESRI

WKT1:ESRI string:
PROJCS["ETRS_1989_ETRS-GK28FIN",GEOGCS["GCS_ETRS_1989",DATUM["D_ETRS_1989",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",28.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

The version of Proj can be checked with command "Proj"

```
proj
Rel. 9.2.0, March 1st, 2023
```

and then the corresponding EPSG database version can be checked from https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/releases

```
9.2.0 Release Notes
EPSG updated to EPSG 10.082 (#3609)
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response. But I can find only WKT 2 string on this web. What about WKT 1 or ESRI WKT?

Comment: EPSG supports only EPSG codes and current encodings. Of the two sites epsg.io is more up to date. I will also edit my answer and add an alternative for finding the strings with Proj.